# how to grab button class name created in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var inputEl=document.querySelector("#input-bar");
    var addBtnEl=document.querySelector("#btn");
    var ulEl=document.querySelector("#output-line");
    // var list=document.querySelector(".list");
    console.log(inputEl);
    let savedIn=[];
    addBtnEl.addEventListener("click",function(){
        savedIn.push(inputEl.value);
        console.log(savedIn);
        console.log(savedIn.length);
        for(let i=0;i<savedIn.length;i++){
            var sample=`<li class="list">${savedIn[i]}</li><button class="tick"><span id="tick-span">&#10003;</span></button><br>`;
            console.log("in for");
        }
        ulEl.innerHTML+=sample;
        // ulEl.innerHTML+=`<li>helloo</li><button>hiii</button>`;
    });
    // tickbtn.addEventListener("click",function(){
        //     // list.style.backgroundColor="blue";
        //     console.log("tick btn");  
        
        // }); 
        var tickbtn=document.getElementsByClassName("tick"); 
console.log(tickbtn);

**
```

1. i have create a button and added class name ="tick

"

2. and i try to grab class name of button but its not grabbing and
   logging out on console
3. how do I grab button class name "tick"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing your code on https://codepen.io/pen/ (which i recommend you to use for quick frontend stuff), I come up to the following solution :

```js
var inputEl=document.querySelector("#input-bar");
var addBtnEl=document.querySelector("#btn");
var ulEl=document.querySelector("#output-line");
// var list=document.querySelector(".list");
console.log(inputEl);
let savedIn=[];

function f() {
  savedIn.push(inputEl.value);
  for(let i=0;i<savedIn.length;i++){
    var sample=`<li class="list">${savedIn[i]}</li><button class="tick"><span id="tick-span">&#10003;</span></button><br>`;
    console.log("in for");
  }
  ulEl.innerHTML+=sample;
}
function g() {
  var tickbtn = document.getElementsByClassName("tick"); 
  console.log(tickbtn[0]);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-bar">
<button id="btn" onclick="f(); g()">Click</button>
<div id="output-line"></div>
```

Like that the output won't be undefined anymore ; it will display the first button (`tickbtn[0]`). And as I told you above in the comments section, it's preferably to not use event listeners **in this situation**.
For any other problem, do not hesitate.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
var tickbtn=document.getElementsByClassName("tick")[0];
```

Comment: showing undefined in console

Comment: Sure cz you defined it only. Display it now : console.log(tickbtn)

Comment: i did console.log(tickbtn) showing undefined

Comment: Then there are no html elements in your html page with the class "tick". Please check this.

Comment: i have crreated a button in javascript ,look in the function where i have gave button class name tick

Comment: Ok i think the problem is with the event listener. By the time your script reached the end (**var tickbtn=document.getElementsByClassName("tick"); 
console.log(tickbtn);**), the event listner hasn't yet been triggered (i.e. button addBtnEl still not clicked) and thus no element with the class "tick". When you click addBtnEl, ok there will class "tick" but it's too late : your script won't return to the instruction var tickbtn = etc.